# Specifying required attribute whilst creating a new html element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to dynamically create input HTML elements with the required property.

The element is being created fine however the required property is being shown as 'required'='required' upon inspecting the HTML element.

How can I add the required attribute whilst creating the input element?

```
jQuery('<input />', {
            'type':'text',
            'text': "Ticket Flow Name",
            'name':'setTicketFlowName'+cleanedLastUsedIDNumber,
            'id':'setTicketFlowName'+cleanedLastUsedIDNumber,
            'class':'select2dropdown',
            'required':true
        }).appendTo('#innercontainer1_TicketFlowName'+cleanedLastUsedIDNumber);
```

Comment: You're already doing that. `required="required"` is fine. Why didn't you test this before posting here?

Comment: i did, it still allows me to submit the form

Comment: Not for me it doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/g9fd8m70/

Comment: I found out that the required property isnt working due to the submit button being of type button rather than submit, thanks for helping me debug in the right direction.

You might want to do a post so that i can select it as the answer

Comment: Yeah, adding `type="button"` to a button inside a form will specifically prevent it from submitting the form.

Comment: Do you know how i can use type=button but still retain the validation provided by the required attribute?

Comment: Why do you want to use type=button in the first place? Are you handling the button's click event instead of the form's submission event? What I'm saying is, this new question sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Yes I actually have an event handler for the button which will allow me to modify the data being sent over in the PUT request.

Hence if possible, i would like to continue using type=button but at the same time use the required attribute

Comment: If it's just about modifying the data before the form is sent the regular way (i.e. non-ajax), like I said, use the form's submission event. It runs in between the required check and the form actually being sent. i.e. use `$('#theform').on('submit', function(e) {...})` instead. If you DO make an ajax request, do the exact same thing but also prevent the form submission by calling `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you!!